# Any additional benefit of using JS Minification although there is browser caching?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, bundling-and-minification

When client resources (JS & css) downloaded to browser from cdn (or asp.net mvc bundled). These will be cached on the browser side (assuming I did not enabled always download options). Having said this minifying resource benefit in faster download only first time. Other than network bandwidth what is the benefit of having resource minification. I am asking this question because I am curious to know if it improves JS engine performance on browser side with minified JS resource. I might be missing something. Thanks for your answer..

Answer (score 1):

Good question,

First of all, I do encourage you to always use minified css and javascript in your production environment. This obviously also counts for your own code.

I can't tell you for sure that the javascript will be executed faster or not, because I never tested it. However I would assume it would, since javascript has to be parsed by the javascript engine. All the unnecessary spaces, newlines, long variable names, etc. will take some time to parse (even though the impact might be very minimal).

Even if there would not be any change in time, there is a good reason to use the minified CND version of a library. Probably most other websites or web apps will use the minified version, so the chances are higher your visitor already has the minified version cached, compared to the not minified version.

Answer (score 0):

If the resource is already cached on the client's browser there is no benefit at all since the client doesn't have to load anything (it already is), if it isn't cached then it could save bandwidth if you minify it. That is all.

Comment: Can you provide some form of proof that the minified javascript has no performance benefit for parsing/compiling? You stated it as fact, but my gut tells me there might be some benefits... Smaller file could mean less time to parse.

Comment: I stated that if it is already cached it doesn't matter since there is nothing to load, and nothing will be done.

Comment: that has nothing to do with parsing the js file and executing it. That has to do with downloading it. My point is compiling a file that has 20KB in it seems like it should be faster than compiling a file that has 40KB in it. You are definitively saying "no," I'm asking you to back that up. Forget the download piece. Let's talk JS engine compilation and execution time.